# Windbg: Is there a way to Import/Export native breakpoints?

Tags: windbg, breakpoints

Is there a way to Import/Export native breakpoints?

What I do now is have a notepad of interesting breakpoints like the following.

```
bp foo!bar;bp foo!barbar; bp foo!barbarbar; .................
```

I run the above manually each time by copy and pasting it from notepad to windbg's command window.

P.S. Is there a way to tell windbg to run the notepad file directly? instead of copy and pasting?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute a script do this:

```
$<"myScript.txt"
```

The above assumes you don't need to pass arguements (for more options see links at end).

If you want to save your breakpoints note that you can just save your workspace and then WinDbg will reload all your current breakpoints and reapply them, except for address breakpoints for obvious reasons.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You can also start WinDbg with the `-c` to pass a command like so:

```
WinDbg -c "bp foo!bar;bp foo!barbar; bp foo!barbarbar;"
```

You could also save them into a `.cmdtree` file, see [here](http://voneinem-windbg.blogspot.co.uk/2008/09/amazing-helper-cmdtree.html) for an example file and more info in a [blogpost](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2008/09/17/special-command-execute-commands-from-a-customized-user-interface-with-cmdtree.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

if you want to save breakpoints but do not want to use work spaces and re use the breakpoints

do this

```
.logopen break.txt;.bpcmds;.logclose
```

and then when you want to re apply

simply do `$<break.txt`

a sample

```
0:000> bl
0:000> bp calc!WinMain
0:000> bp calc!atanhrat
0:000> bu ntdll!ZwCreateIoCompletion ".echo foo"
0:000> bu ntdll!ZwCreateIoCompletion ".echo foo;gc"
breakpoint 2 redefined
0:000> bp calc!xorrat
0:000> g

Breakpoint 0 hit

calc!WinMain:
01001f51 b8ee280101      mov     eax,offset calc!terminate+0x6 (010128ee)
0:000> .logopen break.txt
Opened log file 'break.txt'
0:000> .bpcmds
bp0 0x01001f51 ;
bp1 0x0101090e ;
bu2 ntdll!ZwCreateIoCompletion ".echo foo;gc";
bp3 0x0100c474 ;
0:000> .logclose
Closing open log file break.txt
0:000> .restart

ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
7c90120e cc              int     3
0:000> bl  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<---------------- no breakpoints in new calc.exe 
0:000> $<break.txt
0:000> Opened log file 'break.txt'
        ^ Syntax error in 'Opened log file 'break.txt''
0:000> 0:000> .bpcmds
       ^ Syntax error in '0:000> .bpcmds'
0:000> bp0 0x01001f51 ;
0:000> bp1 0x0101090e ;
0:000> bu2 ntdll!ZwCreateIoCompletion ".echo foo;gc";
0:000> bp3 0x0100c474 ;
0:000> 0:000> .logclose
       ^ Syntax error in '0:000> .logclose'

0:000> bl  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<--------------------------- all old bps restored
 0 e 01001f51     0001 (0001)  0:**** calc!WinMain
 1 e 0101090e     0001 (0001)  0:**** calc!atanhrat
 2 e 7c90d0be     0001 (0001)  0:**** ntdll!NtCreateIoCompletion ".echo foo;gc"
 3 e 0100c474     0001 (0001)  0:**** calc!xorrat
```

Comment: Very nifty. Gave a +1, but you might want to mention where the break.txt file is saved.